# how to resolve an .hgtags conflict?

Tags: mercurial

I can't resolve this conflict to .hgtags

```
kd:friend-sup/ $ cat .hgtags
<<<<<<< MINE
42569bf07912cd317b9305082d980cb64b318042 106.00
42569bf07912cd317b9305082d980cb64b318042 106.01
45846a087b03e656fcf1f986d39c095fbae2ed9e 106.02
45846a087b03e656fcf1f986d39c095fbae2ed9e 106.03
c45c61fdfe20fa088a4418fef55ba93930d6dbe0 106.04
c45c61fdfe20fa088a4418fef55ba93930d6dbe0 106.05
c45c61fdfe20fa088a4418fef55ba93930d6dbe0 106.06
c45c61fdfe20fa088a4418fef55ba93930d6dbe0 106.07
||||||| ANCESTOR
=======
ea8e577c2cfc6538da32c16ba4248d27768223bd raw-qf-merge--main-trunk
>>>>>>> OTHER
```

I tried editing the file in various ways, removing the markers, to no avail. Ideally I want the tags from MINE and OTHER, so just remove the markers.

```
kd:friend-sup/ $ vi .hgtags
```

the failure:

```
kd:friend-sup/ $ hg resolve .hgtags
merging .hgtags
merging .hgtags failed!
kd:friend-sup/ $ cat .hgtags
<<<<<<< MINE
42569bf07912cd317b9305082d980cb64b318042 106.00
42569bf07912cd317b9305082d980cb64b318042 106.01
45846a087b03e656fcf1f986d39c095fbae2ed9e 106.02
45846a087b03e656fcf1f986d39c095fbae2ed9e 106.03
c45c61fdfe20fa088a4418fef55ba93930d6dbe0 106.04
c45c61fdfe20fa088a4418fef55ba93930d6dbe0 106.05
c45c61fdfe20fa088a4418fef55ba93930d6dbe0 106.06
c45c61fdfe20fa088a4418fef55ba93930d6dbe0 106.07
||||||| ANCESTOR
=======
ea8e577c2cfc6538da32c16ba4248d27768223bd raw-qf-merge--main-trunk
>>>>>>> OTHER
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to mark the merge conflict in the file as solved, so you should use the `-m` option:

```
hg resolve -m .hgtags
```

Without that, `hg resolve` retries to merge the file, overwriting your manual changes.

The relevant part of `hg resolve --help`:

> The resolve command can be used in the following ways:
>
> - "`hg resolve [--tool TOOL] FILE...`": attempt to re-merge the specified
>       files, discarding any previous merge attempts. Re-merging is not
>       performed for files already marked as resolved. Use "--all/-a" to
>       selects all unresolved files. "`--tool`" can be used to specify the merge
>       tool used for the given files. It overrides the HGMERGE environment
>       variable and your configuration files.
> - "`hg resolve -m [FILE]`": mark a file as having been resolved (e.g. after
>       having manually fixed-up the files). The default is to mark all
>       unresolved files.